# Pygame sound mixer stopping program from running?

Tags: python, audio, tkinter, pygame

I am finishing a game for Pyweek and the simplest way to add sound (at least, I understood how to do this one) was to use Pygame. My problem is, no matter where I start playing it, it stops the program which I obviously don't need. (It basically pauses it) even when I run it before my game starts (written in Tkinter and pygame for a couple elements like sound.) Help!

Code for the music play: (I can hear it when it plays but stops program)

```
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("export.wav")
mixer.music.play()
while mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
    continue
```

Comment: I'm curious, what happens if you take out the `while` loop? I've never used tkinter before but I know if I use pygame from a python console session that once I start playing the music I'm free to enter the next commands while the music playes. However, that loop is going to stop me doing anything until the music is over.

Comment: Sorry i meant to delete this, i fixed it awhile ago using a 2nd script

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is single threaded. If you have a long running function such as playing a sound, you need to run that in a separate thread or process.

Comment: How would I do that? I would like an example and explanation please.